# |Θ(f(n)) − O(f(n))| confusion

Tags: analysis

`|Θ(f(n)) − O(f(n))|` is something that gave me some problems.

So I demonstrated (I don't know if it is correct) that gave me the result : `Θ(f(n))`, but it looks weird and I don't know what to say.

On the other hand, at the second attempt to solve this problem the result was: `omega(f(n))`. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Purely mathematical topics are better addressed in the [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Alternatively, you can also post this at cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: What does the operator − represent here? If symmetric difference and theta/omicron are taken to be sets, then the answer I think is o(f(n)) possibly.

Comment: @Patrick87 can't be symmetric difference, because of the ||, so must mean absolute value of all pairwise subtractions.  In that case *g(n) = f(n) - f(n) = 0* is certainly in |Θ(f(n)) − O(f(n))|, but not necessarily in Θ(f(n))

Comment: @Patrick87 I'd think |Θ(f(n)) − O(f(n))| means |g(n) - h(n)| where g(n) ∈ Θ(f(n)) and h(n) ∈ O(f(n)). There are many people who write things like O(n) + O(n), so that would make sense. But that syntax is quite informal. Formally I'd say either it means something different from what was intended or it has no clear meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, as Dukeling commented, that you mean `|g(n) - h(n)|` where `g(n) ∈ Θ(f(n))` and `h(n) ∈ O(f(n))`.
if `h(n) === 0` the the result is `g(n)` which is `Θ(f(n))`.
If `h(n) = g(n)` then the result is `0` which is `O(f(n))` but no longer `Θ(f(n))`. But always, `|g(n) - h(n)| <= 2 * max{|g(n)|, |h(n)|} ∈ O(f(n))`.
To conclude, the result is sometimes `Θ(f(n))`, and sometimes it's less (actually, for every function `t(n) ∈ O(f(n))` you can find some `g, h` such the the result is in `Θ(t(n))`) but th result is always in `O(f(n))`, thus never in `ω(f(n))`.